# How to start newly built docker image when deploying?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

I've created a gitlab-ci.yml pipeline to deploy a simple react.js application.
I installed the gitlab-runner on EC2 (AWS) and inside my pipeline I build the image and push it to the registry.

This is my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

 test-build: 
   stage: test
   only:
     - master
   tags:
     - master
   script:
     - sudo docker build .

deploy-production:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - master
  before_script:
    # remove the offending package golang-docker-credential-helpers without removing all of docker-compose
    - sudo dpkg -r --ignore-depends=golang-docker-credential-helpers golang-docker-credential-helpers
    - sudo docker version
    - "sudo docker info"
    - "sudo docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
  script:
    - "sudo docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest --pull ."
    - "sudo docker push ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest"
    - "sudo docker run -it -d -p 80:80 --rm --name daruma.comunicato ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest"
  after_script:
    - "sudo docker logout ${CI_REGISTRY}"
  when: manual
```

The problem is: how do I run the latest pushed image?
If I run `docker run -it ...` the pipeline fails with:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/app.test" is already in use by container "f8e888d6dff6fe5808d7577fe8fddc3e24cd8cc0e248a69d36e7ce51bf339ae6". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Because that container is already running and has the same name.
I don't want to stop all containers when deploying because I could have other docker containers running. I also thought to do `docker stop app.test && docker rm app.test` but if for some reason the container is down that will give me an error and won't deploy.

What is the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that you already have a container with that name and docker is not allowing you to have multiple containers with the same name, to fix that, remove the old container, just do in the terminal something like `$docker ps -a` and you will get a list of all containers you have,
then identify the id of the container with that name and do remove it by doing:

```
$docker rm -f <container-id>
```